# Older solution does not work anymore

Tags: ppa, 18.10, flatpak

[What can I do if a repository/PPA I added does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-i-added-does-not-have-a-release-file) does not work in my case.

[image: Terminal]

```
Terminal:/$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:/alexlarsson/flatpak
Output:Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alexlarsson/flatpak/ubuntu cosmic Release      
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Comment: But https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-i-added-does-not-have-a-release-file is not working for me.

Comment: First of all, you probably should describe which of the answers did not work and if you have tried all of them. Also, usually when PPA does not have a release file, it's not something you yourself can fix. You need to contact the maintainer of the PPA and if they can - they will create the PPA version for your OS version as well. Note that this may take some time as developers will need to test if the software works properly on that particular version of the OS

Comment: Can u tell me where i could contact those developer?

Comment: Alex Larson is the maintainer of the package according to the PPA address, so you can contact them via https://launchpad.net/~alexlarsson You will need to have a Lauchpad ID setup to do so